# Sink drain plumbing pipes won't connect

Tags: drain, sink, pipe

I'm installing a new sink and as its visible from the picture the pipes are not aligned and sink pipe is not long enough as well. The pipe coming out of the wall is pretty solid so I didn't try pulling it out trying to align the pipes, as well I can bring the sink base a bit closer to the wall, but that will still be not enough to insert the drain pipe. Is there anything i could use as a connection/adapter between these two? Thanks![image]

Answer (score 1):

While they are not the most correct way to alleviate your problem, check your favorite home center/big box store for a "flexible tail piece extension". The ideal method would be to remove and realign your current drain. While the flexible drains work they are more prone to clogging due to the accordion like walls of the pipe.

Comment: This, a few times. Except that if you use the flex pipe, as a temporary solution, it will lose priority on your list of things to fix properly. It will be the weak link in the chain, and it will clog. When it breaks, the waste water, and whatever is in it will not go somewhere that is easy to clean. Do it right the first time. Or at least buy a bucket and a 2nd piece of flex. Put the bucket under the trap, and gently wire-tie the flex to the drain pipe, so you can find it when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

They do connect.  You have to get the right pieces to make them fit.  I would cut out pipe by wall, I would put a trap under drain pipe, you will need to extend the black pipe with female/female and pipe so that the trap exits at same level as your exit by wall, then add a right angle on top of trap, pipe two wall, and fit it together with female/female.

Comment: A pair of 45 degree angle fittings, and a short piece of pipe to connect the will allow whatever offset you need. And if you are going to use plastic fittings that let you hand tighten them, make all of them that way. Needing a tool for just one fitting is really annoying.